# Stacked Bar-Plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data in a .csv file:
[image]

My code:

```
data1 <- data.frame(read.csv("Graph1.csv"))
dfm <- melt(data1[, c('Week', 'Total.A', 'Total.B')], id.vars = 1)

ggplot(dfm,aes(x = Week,y = value)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), stat = "identity")
```

When I run this I get Week values which are not in my dataset. For ex: 201760.

[image]

Need to fix this issue.

Comment: Looks like Week is a numeric variable here. Try replacing `x = Week` in your `ggplot()` line with `x = factor(Week)`.

Comment: Yes. it worked. Thanks, Z.lin!